# Server not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction

Tags: xml, vb.net, soap

I'm trying to implement a webservice from a software called SmarterTrack just that I'm not getting it ... give me the following error:

Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket.

I already tested it directly in the browser and it works extremely well.

```
Sub Execute()
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx"), HttpWebRequest)
request.Method = "POST"
request.Host = "localhost:9996"
request.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket")
request.Method = "POST"
Dim soapEnvelopeXml As New XmlDocument()
soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"" xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<soap:Body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<CreateTicket xmlns=""http://localhost:9996/Services2/svcTickets.asmx"">" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<authUserName>admin</authUserName>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<authPassword>teste123</authPassword>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<departmentID>3</departmentID>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<groupId>3</groupId>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<userIdOfAgent>2</userIdOfAgent>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<toAddress>teste@teste.pt</toAddress>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<subject>test</subject>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<body>teste</body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<isHtml>True</isHtml>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<setWaiting>True</setWaiting>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"<sendEmail>True</sendEmail>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"</CreateTicket>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"</soap:Body>" & ControlChars.CrLf &
"</soap:Envelope>")
Using stream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream)
End Using
Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Using rd As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
        Dim soapResult As String = rd.ReadToEnd()
        Console.WriteLine(soapResult)
    End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

I imported the following wsdl directly into visual studio as service reference, just mocking the domain. Did I do it correctly?
http://portal.smartertools.com/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?WSDL

Comment: A browser is much smarter than a HttpWebRequest.  The broswer does things automatically that you must add in code.  Best way of solving issue is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Capture results with browser and compare with vb.net app.  The issue is usually with a missing header in the app.  Add missing items to your request.

Comment: Thanks Who is the Best fiddler? Telerik?

Comment: I usually use the Telerik fiddler.  Really does make much difference in this case because you are just looking at the http headers and don't need a lot of fancy features.  Just filter for http and if necessary just the IP address of your client and server.

Answer (score 0):

When looking on this page http://portal.smartertools.com/Services2/svcTickets.asmx?op=CreateTicket you can see sample requests. Note `?op=CreateTicket` as parameter of this test form.

Reading that same page, you'll see this example:

```
SOAPAction: "http://www.smartertools.com/SmarterTrack/Services2/svcTickets.asmx/CreateTicket"
```

and this is the value (maybe with modified host) that you have to send as SOAPAction header into your request.

You've provided URL of test form with `?op=CreateTicket` in your demo but that's not SOAPAction.

Consider SOAPAction to be independent identification of action that has nothing to do with URL of the action itself. Even when it's derived from this URL in .NET web services.

Comment: How do I find the correct SOAPAction I have to use?

Comment: You will read my answer again. You will find URL that you already know in first paragraph. Open it and read the content of that page. You will find SOAPAction in there as noted in code sample. Or you can examine WSDL document and search for soapAction attribute.